# List of Android pre-built UI components

Tags: android, user-interface, components

I was wondering if there is some sort of list, with images (the docs don't have images), of all of the UI components that the Android platform offers?

I've tried looking for some sort of list or anything really, but I can't find anything close. I know Apple/iOS has a number of lists, including [this one](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html), which is EXACTLY the type of thing that I'm looking for. That one came up during my search for an android list.

Comment: `I've tried looking for some sort of list or anything really` [irony mode on]yeah, sure ...[off] start from here ... http://developer.android.com/design/index.html then go to "Building Blocks"

Comment: @Selvin That helps a lot, actually! I get that its on the developer site, but its not written towards developers as it still requires a lot of research as to what each component is. Also, it doesn't come up with google, since I don't initiate my searches on the developer.android site as google is much simpler. Thanks for being a dick about it off the bat, though!

Comment: you know that android is open source ... open source .... open source ... open source(i could do this whole day)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a list with a preview. You already have that in the UI editor in Eclipse:

[image]

Comment: That also is a really big help! However, it doesn't seems to include everything. But I've really been underusing Eclipse!

Comment: It includes *all* default UI widgets :)

Comment: Oh. I can't seem to find the `TabWidget` and a couple others.

Comment: Go to Composite -> Tabs

Comment: Wow. I guess its been a long day! :)